# How do I move a specific part of a string to a new string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

For example, let's say I am using the following strings

```
key = "XPMGTDHLYONZBWEARKJUFSCIQV"
example = "test"
newKey = ""
```

and I want to get a random section of that string and I know the length. So

```
length = len(example)
rand = random.randint(0, len(key) - length)
```

I believe this code will take a random number from 0 to the length of the key minus the example. This should insure that I always have enough letters. The part I am getting stuck on, is how I take the starting point, rand, and the ending point, length, and use them to get a specific part of the key. For example, let's say `rand = 2` and `length = 4`. Then `newKey` should be, `newKey = "MGTD"`.

What string command can I use to get this result?

Comment: Do you really mean "move" here, or just "copy"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply slice the key:

```
newKey = key[rand:rand + length]
```

Demo:

```
>>> length, rand = 4, 2
>>> key = "XPMGTDHLYONZBWEARKJUFSCIQV"
>>> key[rand:rand + length]
'MGTD'
```